# Get temperature from live data if available, else avg over historical data

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am trying to get either live temperature for a trip, if live data is not available get an average temperature from histroical data.
I have made a simple version of my problem, with these tabels:

Trip

```
id  departure_time          arrival_time            location_id
1   2018-04-07 07:00:00     2018-04-14 17:00:00     1
2   2018-04-14 07:00:00     2018-04-21 17:00:00     1
```

Location

```
id      name
1       Location
```

Weather

```
id  temperature date        location_id
1       20      2018-04-07  1
2       20      2018-04-08  1
3       20      2018-04-09  1
4       20      2018-04-10  1
5       20      2018-04-11  1
6       20      2018-04-12  1
7       20      2018-04-13  1
8       20      2018-04-14  1
9       15      2016-04-07  1
10      15      2016-04-08  1
11      15      2016-04-09  1
12      15      2016-04-10  1
13      15      2016-04-11  1
14      15      2016-04-12  1
15      15      2016-04-13  1
16      15      2016-04-14  1
17      19      2017-04-07  1
18      19      2017-04-08  1
19      19      2017-04-09  1
20      19      2017-04-10  1
21      19      2017-04-11  1
22      19      2017-04-12  1
23      19      2017-04-13  1
24      19      2017-04-14  1
25      15      2017-04-15  1
26      15      2017-04-16  1
27      15      2017-04-17  1
28      15      2017-04-18  1
29      15      2017-04-19  1
30      15      2017-04-20  1
31      15      2017-04-21  1
32      19      2016-04-15  1
33      19      2016-04-16  1
34      19      2016-04-17  1
35      19      2016-04-18  1
36      19      2016-04-19  1
37      19      2016-04-20  1
38      19      2016-04-21  1
```

The problem i am having is that since these trips are last-minute trips i have "live" data for trips departing within the next week.
So i would like to get a either live forecast if available, else an avg for the temperature from the years from the previous years.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bce59/3

Here is the approach i took in order to try and solve the problem.

If any details has been forgotten please ask.

Expected result:

```
id  departure_time          arrival_time        location_id temperature
1   2018-04-07 07:00:00     2018-04-14 17:00:00         1           20
1   2018-04-07 07:00:00     2018-04-14 17:00:00         1           20
1   2018-04-07 07:00:00     2018-04-14 17:00:00         1           20
1   2018-04-07 07:00:00     2018-04-14 17:00:00         1           20
1   2018-04-07 07:00:00     2018-04-14 17:00:00         1           20
1   2018-04-07 07:00:00     2018-04-14 17:00:00         1           20
1   2018-04-07 07:00:00     2018-04-14 17:00:00         1           20
1   2018-04-07 07:00:00     2018-04-14 17:00:00         1           20
2   2018-04-14 07:00:00     2018-04-21 17:00:00         1           20
2   2018-04-14 07:00:00     2018-04-21 17:00:00         1           17
2   2018-04-14 07:00:00     2018-04-21 17:00:00         1           17
2   2018-04-14 07:00:00     2018-04-21 17:00:00         1           17
2   2018-04-14 07:00:00     2018-04-21 17:00:00         1           17
2   2018-04-14 07:00:00     2018-04-21 17:00:00         1           17
2   2018-04-14 07:00:00     2018-04-21 17:00:00         1           17
2   2018-04-14 07:00:00     2018-04-21 17:00:00         1           17
```

Comment: Could you provide your expect result?

Comment: I have edited the first post, where i added a expected result, and some more test data in order to emphasize my problem.

If needed a date can be added to the result, in order to get the date of which the temperature is corresponding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `generate_series` function to make a Calendar from `trip` table on subquery.

Then `Left JOIN` on subquery by `dates` you might get match `weather` you can get it temperature. if `temperature` is null on `w.temperature` then get `avg` `temperature`

You can try this.

```
SELECT  t.id,
        t.departure_time,
        t.arrival_time,
        l.id as "location_id",
        coalesce(w.temperature,(select FLOOR(avg(temperature)) from weather)) as "temperature"
FROM 
location l inner join 
(
  select id,
         location_id,
         departure_time,
         arrival_time,
         generate_series(departure_time :: timestamp,arrival_time::timestamp,'1 day'::interval) as dates
  from trip 
) t on t.location_id = l.id LEFT JOIN weather w on t.dates::date = w.date::date
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bce59/48*

**EDIT**

You could use a *CTE* query get `Avg` by `year` instead of the subquery in  `coalesce` function on select clause.

```
WITH weather_avg AS (
    SELECT floor(avg(a)) avgTemp 
    from
    ( 
      SELECT
        extract(YEAR from weather.date) AS YEAR,
        floor(avg(weather.temperature)) a
      FROM weather
      group by extract(YEAR from weather.date) 
    ) t
)
SELECT  t.id,
        t.departure_time,
        t.arrival_time,
        t.location_id as "location_id",
        coalesce(w.temperature,(select avgTemp from weather_avg)) as "temperature"
FROM 
(
  select t.id,
         t.location_id,
         t.departure_time,
         t.arrival_time,
         generate_series(departure_time :: timestamp,arrival_time::timestamp,'1 day'::interval) as dates
  from trip  t inner join location l on t.location_id = l.id
) t LEFT JOIN weather w 
on t.dates::date = w.date::date
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bce59/76*

Comment: I can see you are inner joining on location, is it possible to join on trip instead of the location?

Comment: It's my pleasure:)

Comment: I have a small question, the subquery in coalesce, dont that just take the  average temperature of the entire weather table? ignoreing the date?

Comment: found out since it's using the weather from the join

Comment: You can use a `CTE` query to get `Avg` by year instead of the subquery like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bce59/76